# How to move from Bottom Navigation Bar to activity android

Tags: android

I add to my app Bottom Navigation Bar it's work but the problem now I want move from one button in  Bottom Navigation Bar to activity that activity have to fragment to view (TabLayout,ViewPager).
When I try to make it like that   selectedFragment = new MainActivityOderLIstFargmant(); the show me error like that ..
and also like that and also not work.. startActivity(new Intent(NafMain.this, MainActivityOderLIstFargmant.class));

[image]

I need to move to other activity to show two (TabLayout,ViewPager).

this activity I want to move to it ..

```
public class MainActivityOderLIstFargmant extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageAdapterOrderList pageAdapterOrderList;
    TabItem tabChats;
    TabItem tabCalls;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mani_order_list);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabChats = findViewById(R.id.tabChats);
        tabCalls = findViewById(R.id.tabCalls);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        pageAdapterOrderList = new PageAdapterOrderList(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapterOrderList);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    }
}
```

from here

```
public class NafMaintest extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_naf_main);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
            bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                           selectedFragment = new MainActivityOderLIstFargmant();//I try like that but not work 
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_favorites:
                            selectedFragment = new FragmentHome();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_search:
                            selectedFragment = new FragmentProfile();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_s:
                            selectedFragment = new MainActivity();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;

                }
            });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new FragmentHome()).commit();
        }
    }



}
```

If anyone know how solution it help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to instantiate `MainActivityOderLIstFargmant` activity in the switch `case R.id.nav_home` and put it into a `Fragment` variable which is called `selectedFragment`, so both types are different (Fragment & Activity). That is why the screenshot you provided says **Incompatible types**.

To get your code works you can change the switch case as below

```
case R.id.nav_home:
    Intent intent = new Intent(NafMaintest.this, MainActivityOderLIstFargmant.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true; // use return to avoid triggering the fragment transaction after the `swtich` block
```

Comment: brother ..your code is working but one problem come ..when I use your code the Bottom Navigation Bar Disappears or Hide

Comment: Hello @marwan .. There is a difference between Fragment and Activity .. The activity can have multiple fragments, and this is what your `NafMaintest` does which includes all the fragments of the `BottomNavigationBar`, also the xml layout of  `NafMaintest` activity contains this `BottomNavigationBar`, when you start a new activity, the new activity has a separate layout file that might not have the `BottomNavigationBar` .. in this example it's `MainActivityOderLIstFargmant`

Comment: You can solve this by making `MainActivityOderLIstFargmant` a fragment not an activity ... or add `BottomNavigationBar` with its fragments to `MainActivityOderLIstFargmant`  activity.. the latter solution is kind of duplicate; so the first one may be more efficient

Comment: I have try your first solution you mentioned, which is to convert the MainActivityOderLIstFargmant  activity to fragment and it's work fine but I face one problem when I move from button of BottomNavigationBar from activtiy MainActivityOderLIstFargmant to another page and I come back to it the page stops and does not work ..Is there a solution to this problem you have?Almost I need to refresh the page, whatever I return to, I expect that this will solve the problem

Comment: @marwan  So the problem when you navigate between different buttons of the `BottomNavigationBar ` .. you might lose fragment data right?

Comment: I guess you can save data into a shared ViewModel as you know fragments have life cycles same as activities

Comment: I think this problem come because I move from fragment (TabLayout,ViewPager). to activity  Bottom Navigation Bar

Comment: Maybe.. I guess you can open a new question for this to add the full data and  keep it with a separate request as it is beyond the scope of this question..